# VBA .Pagesetup row doesn't update

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this routine to print out Pivot Tables of each file. (`codeConv`) when testing it with F8, step by step, everything works fine. Last row and last column works fine,
When calling the routine via `Call PrintLoyerPivot(codeConv)` or running it with F5, the `PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRowSAS).Address`  doesn't seem to work. It will always only print the first line, as if Print Area was `ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & 1")`

VBA:

```
   Sub PrintLoyerPivot(ByVal codeConv As String)

   Dim filter As PivotItem
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lastRowSAS As Long
   Dim lastColSAS As Long
   
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll


   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").ClearAllFilters

   For Each filter In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").PivotItems
       If filter.Caption = codeConv And filter.RecordCount > 0 Then GoTo SetFilter1
   Next filter
   GoTo notfound

   SetFilter1:
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").CurrentPage = codeConv

       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("loyer_pivot")
       lastRowSAS = [LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]
       lastColSAS = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
       ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, lastColSAS).Address, "$")(1)

       ws.Calculate
       ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRowSAS).Columns.AutoFit


   With ws.PageSetup
           .PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRowSAS).Address
           .PrintQuality = 600
           .Orientation = xlLandscape
           .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
           .FitToPagesWide = 1
           .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
           .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
   End With

  ws.PrintOut
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  notfound:

  End Sub
```

I have the same problem in another PivotTable Printout script. But there the last line is often too high, so it prints what it should plus some extra blank pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "Pagesetup row"?

Comment: `[LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]` returns the last row of the _active sheet_ could this be the source of the error?

Comment: absolutely...added a `ws.activate` before the `lastRowSAS = [LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]`.... now it works. Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ike it works now like this:

I just added `ws.activate` befor `lastRowSAS = LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]`

```
Sub PrintLoyerPivot(ByVal codeConv As String)

   Dim filter As PivotItem
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lastRowSAS As Long
   Dim lastColSAS As Long
   
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").ClearAllFilters

   For Each filter In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").PivotItems
       If filter.Caption = codeConv And filter.RecordCount > 0 Then GoTo SetFilter1
   Next filter
   GoTo notfound

   SetFilter1:
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("loyer_pivot").PivotTables("LoyerParCode").PivotFields("CodeConv").CurrentPage = codeConv

       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("loyer_pivot")
       ws.activate
       lastRowSAS = [LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]
       lastColSAS = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
       ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, lastColSAS).Address, "$")(1)

       ws.Calculate
       ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRowSAS).Columns.AutoFit


   With ws.PageSetup
           .PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRowSAS).Address
           .PrintQuality = 600
           .Orientation = xlLandscape
           .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
           .FitToPagesWide = 1
           .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
           .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
   End With

  ws.PrintOut
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  notfound:

  End Sub
```